# Bundle cache was not change to new version after restart server

Tags: websphere, osgi

In websphere 8.5, i have deployed a new version of bundle(in internal bundle repository and already delete the old one) that was shared in many bundles(asset). After restart the server i found that it still used the old one(see in the bundle cache). My question is why it's not uses the new one and how to solve this problem? I don't want to re-install all bundles.

Thanks,
anurak

Comment: Do you have an OSGi webconsole? Could you please push the refresh button on the bundles screen? If it solves your problem, I will tell the cause :).

Comment: Hi Balaszs, Yes, WAS it has a osgi console but i don't see any refresh button or anything that will point me to do a refresh bundle. I know that why the osgi need to maintain the cache version  and i know that the refresh will release that cache and use the new one. My problem is i don't know how to do a refreshment in WAS because of there nothing i can do on it's osgi console. What i can do now is just manual uninstall all bundles that used that old bundle in cacahe and install them agains and that isn't what i want to do. Any comments, please. --anurak

Comment: I meant this screen: http://jaceklaskowski.pl/w/images/2/2f/Jbossas7-osgi-jboss-osgi-web-console.png. See the "Refresh packages" on the right top part of the screen. I do not know about WAS, but in OSGi, the wires between bundles are not refreshed until "Refresh packages" is called even if the bundle that the wire points to is removed.

Comment: Try to run `osgiCfgInit -all` to clear the caches. [osgiCfgInit](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_osgicfginit_script.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-18-9-84&lang=en)

Comment: Is it a command in was? I will check and try that. Thanks.